# dedicated IC for PWM

Tags: microcontroller, led, pwm

Is it okay to drive leds through PWM directly from Microcontroller? OR should I use a dedicated PM generator IC like NCP5623? the Microcontroller uses software pwm. what are the pros and cons of both

Comment: There are microcontrollers where PWM could be  generated by hardware timers.

Comment: Are you taking about a microcontroller that you're using? There's plenty of microcontrollers that have PWM controllers built-in.

Comment: @BenceKaulics software assisted PWM and purely software based PWM is fairly common.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for the correction, it was a premature statement from me. But then the question is about pros and cons of hardware and software PWM or pros and cons of PWM generated by uC and dedicated IC?

Answer (score 2):

Software PWM:

- More control over PWM period and frequency
- Lower part count
- Taxes the processor

Dedicated PWM Driver:

- Delegates control to the dedicated IC leaving your Microcontroller free to do other things
- Lowers development and debugging time. The IC just works.
- Higher BOM
- Likely has higher output/input voltages
- A Dedicated LED Driver will have other features like current control and dot correction.

Comment: It boils down to your dev time vs your dev costs.